# Windows Phone 7.8 and wma audio streaming problems

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, audio-streaming, wma, windows-phone-7.8

Our application streams  wma audio content using AudioPlayerAgent (background player). Everything worked perfectly on WP 7.5 until the update to WP 7.8  has been released. Than it stopped streaming.

To exclude errors in our code we downloaded the Microsoft's example application sdkBackgroundAudioPlayerCS and used our streams. It worked correctly on phones that haven't got the 7.8 update yet, but not on already updated devices.

The streaming works perfectly also on WP8 (we used the binary created for OS 7.1, placed on Store)...

Is there a known workaround for this issue except using different protocol/format?

Here are similar issues:

- http://www.ignii.com/software/?p=377
- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wpapps/wma/9a693cce-478a-438c-91eb-188f48c71945
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/d34d9b0b-79a3-426b-aaa9-e8f17c0e8e8c/
- http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/winphone/forum/wp7-wpmusic/wp7-support-live-streaming-the-next-update-78/548be861-cc4e-4bb9-98b2-448741c54a5e?msgId=8970a7e6-17a8-47e7-8f0b-2ec302ed62e3